# Keyword not supported: 'provider'. I don't know how to fix this error

Tags: vb.net

Private conn As New SqlConnection("Provider=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database1.sdf")

Comment: [SQL Server Compact connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) -- [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: The `SqlClient` namespace, e.g. the `SqlConnection` class, is for SQL Server only. If you want to connect to a SQL Server CE database then you need to use completely different types. The connection string you have wouldn't be valid in either case.